# An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker

Tags: c#, .net, objectcontext, nopcommerce

I'm having a problem with nopcommerce 1.9, and really need some assistance please.

The work I'm doing is to add a product importer into the existing functionality.

On first run after an iisreset, the importer runs fine. The second time after however and any further instance produces the above error. This seems to constantly happen when running the following code IoC.Resolve().UpdateProduct(product). The code that this calls is below:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Updates the product
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="product">Product</param>
    public void UpdateProduct(Product product)
    {
        if (product == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("product");

        product.Name = CommonHelper.EnsureNotNull(product.Name);
        product.Name = CommonHelper.EnsureMaximumLength(product.Name, 400);
        product.ShortDescription = CommonHelper.EnsureNotNull(product.ShortDescription);
        product.FullDescription = CommonHelper.EnsureNotNull(product.FullDescription);
        product.AdminComment = CommonHelper.EnsureNotNull(product.AdminComment);
        product.MetaKeywords = CommonHelper.EnsureNotNull(product.MetaKeywords);
        product.MetaKeywords = CommonHelper.EnsureMaximumLength(product.MetaKeywords, 400);
        product.MetaDescription = CommonHelper.EnsureNotNull(product.MetaDescription);
        product.MetaDescription = CommonHelper.EnsureMaximumLength(product.MetaDescription, 4000);
        product.MetaTitle = CommonHelper.EnsureNotNull(product.MetaTitle);
        product.MetaTitle = CommonHelper.EnsureMaximumLength(product.MetaTitle, 400);
        product.SEName = CommonHelper.EnsureNotNull(product.SEName);
        product.SEName = CommonHelper.EnsureMaximumLength(product.SEName, 100);

        if (!_context.IsAttached(product))
            _context.Products.Attach(product);

        _context.SaveChanges();

        if (this.CacheEnabled)
        {
            _cacheManager.RemoveByPattern(PRODUCTS_PATTERN_KEY);
            _cacheManager.RemoveByPattern(PRODUCTVARIANTS_PATTERN_KEY);
            _cacheManager.RemoveByPattern(TIERPRICES_PATTERN_KEY);
            _cacheManager.RemoveByPattern(CUSTOMERROLEPRICES_PATTERN_KEY);
        }

        //raise event             
        EventContext.Current.OnProductUpdated(null,
            new ProductEventArgs() { Product = product });
    }
```

I don't have very much experience with this type of technology (ObjectContexts), so if a complete solution could be provided, that would be very much appreciated. I've seen lots of examples of this error across the internet, but haven't found a solution that works/makes sense to me. From what I've read, what is apparently happening is that the product is being attached to two different ObjectContexts. I assume this is what's happening here, but I don't know enough about the technology to find out where/why. I tried detaching after SaveChanges, so that the next time it ran it wouldn't reattach the same object but that hasn't been the solution as I expected it to be...

Many thanks, Adrian.

Comment: And when you debug, does it execute the Attach(product) statement?

Comment: That's the line it errors on.

Answer (score 1):

Is product being cached across postbacks?  Typically that happens when the object is static, but it was originally queried on initial page load and then updated in a postback, something like that.  The reason it happens is because the object context it knows that it was queried from was a different INSTANCE than the one you have here.

If you first Detach the entity by using the `Detach` method, then you'll be able to do this.  Otherwise, please provide more information about:

- Is the object context stored statically?
- Is the entity cached?
- Where is _context defined and how are you instantiating the context?

HTH.

Comment: Hi Brian,

The object isn't stored statically. It's defined in the same file as UpdateProduct(Product)
        private readonly NopObjectContext _context;

The function of the updater currently fires after clicking a link button, but once complete it will fire after a windows service calls it. "Product" is cached for speed purposes, and this cache is access during the postback.

The whole ProductService.cs file can be found here if it helps:
http://pastebin.com/yP0deSVB

Any help would be appreciated. I have tried detaching the context after savechanges(), but that hasn't solved the problem.

Comment: Sorry - everything in the ImportProduct class is static. Is this not allowed, or should there be a way around this?

Comment: Essentially, if the objectcontext is stored statically across web requests, it will cause a problem like this.  The  workaround is to store it only for the current HTTP request, using a dictionary like the Page.Items collection or HttpContext.Current.Items collection.  These only live for the current request.

Comment: Thanks Brian. I'm not entirely sure what it was I did - probably something to do with the caching, but I seem to have sorted my problem. Thanks for your help.